# ember route pass dynamic url to child route

Tags: ember.js, routes

if I have defined routes below:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('user', {path: "/:user"}, function () {
        this.route('work', {path: "/work"});
    })
});
```

I can get the :user value in user controller,but How can I get this value in my work controller or work route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `modelFor` in route and set `user` controller property in `model` (or `beforeModel`, `afterModel`) hook:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor

```
//work route
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    user: this.modelFor('user'), // here user is routeName
    work: // your logic here
  });
},

setupController: function(controller, models) {
  controller.setProperties(models);
}
```

Comment: Is there any better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on the controller from the work route in the `setupController` hook:

```
setupController(controller) {
  controller.set('userId', this.modelFor('user').get('id'));
  return this._super(...arguments);
}
// ES < 6 syntax
setupController: function(controller) {
  controller.set('userId', this.modelFor('user').get('id'));
  return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
}
```